# Rails: Update a column with the value of a column in another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-postgresql

I have basically the following code:

```
ModelA.join(:modelB).update_all('modelA.column = modelB.column')
```

That fails with:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "modelB"
LINE 1: ..." SET modelAs.column = modelBs...
                                                         ^
UPDATE "modelAs" SET modelAs.column = modelBs.column WHERE "modelAs"."id" IN (
  SELECT "modelAs"."id" FROM "modelAs" INNER JOIN "modelBs" ON "modelBs"."id" = "modelAs"."modelB_id"
)
```

Looking at the generated sql request, it is pretty obvious that Postgresql expects the modelB table to appear in the update part of the query. It there a way to do that or is it a bug?

(The issue is specific to Postgresql / the Postgresql rails adapter. The code above works fine with MySQL, the joins clause are also copied in the update part of the request)

Comment: Are you sure that this is supposed to work? I think you need to call select for the value.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's supposed to work. The documentation is not clear about it. But it works with MySQL!

Comment: Selecting the value does not help.

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13496